# How I reload the page when I click Link component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logout

I'm making a Logout function with reactJS. When I click Logout button, the token of the localstorage is deleted. But, although the localstroage is deleted, my header can't notice the change before I reload the page.(When the page is root page "/". If the page is not root page, it works well.) How can I solve this??

```
<Link to="/" onClick={AuthenticationService.logout} className="headerBtn">
     logout
</Link>
```

```
logout() {
     localStorage.removeItem("authenticatedUser");
     localStorage.removeItem("token");
         }
```

Comment: history.push('/to_root_page');

Comment: Are you using React Router?

Comment: @ZarNiKoKo / Where do I  put in that code?

Comment: @dalmo3 / Yes. I use BrowserRouter. `<Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />`

Comment: after line of localStorage.removeItem("token");
props.histroy.push();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to **reload** the whole page or just **render** it again, following this change in state?

re-render is much faster than browser reload, because it will only update the needed parts instead of reopening your whole web app again.

If you do have react's state where you could keep an indication whether a user is logged in or not, then calling `setState()` within your `logout()` function would re-render your view.

Comment: Wow. I moved logout function into Header component, and I added this.setState in logout function. So, it works well. I appreciate your thankful advisor.